# why just an augmented assignment statement in python code breaks it?

Tags: python, if-statement, binary-search

why this python code runs normally although the output is incorrect

```
low = 1
high = 1000

print(f"I will guess a value from {low} and {high}"
      "press 'h' or 'l' or 'c'for complete anything else to exit")

guesses = 1 
while True:
    mid = low + (high - low) // 2  
    print("is this is your guess {}".format(mid))
    inp = input()
    if inp == 'h':
        low += 1

    elif inp =='l':
        high -= 1

    elif inp == 'c':
        print('got it')

    else:
        break
```

but when i add just this line of code it says invalid syntax and breaks

```
low = 1
high = 1000

print(f"I will guess a value from {low} and {high}"
      "press 'h' or 'l' or 'c'for complete anything else to exit")

guesses = 1 
while True:
    mid = low + (high - low) // 2  
    print("is this is your guess {}".format(mid))
    inp = input()
    if inp == 'h':
        low += 1

    elif inp =='l':
        high -= 1

    elif inp == 'c':
        print('got it')

    guesses += 1
    else:
        break
```

so why `guesses += 1` just breaks everything it is just a counter it does not have any role in the code except count for how many times i looped

- if you can also tell me why this code doesn't print print predicted values will be appreciated the program is supposed to be a binary search program .

Comment: `if`, `elif`, and `else` must be next to each other - the only thing that's allowed to be between them is whitespace, and the contents of their block. The problem here is being caused by `guesses += 1` being in-between the `elif` and `else`, *on the same level of indentation* - `else` doesn't allow this and will throw an error.

Comment: Just move it below the `else: break` lines.

Comment: thank you i got it know but do you have any idea why this code doesnt print expected output

Comment: You gave us neither the input that you gave your program, nor the output vs the expected output. We can't guess what you expected just by seeing code that doesn't output it.

Comment: You're increasing/decreasing by 1, that's not how binary search is supposed to work. You should take the middle value between the start and the end and check it. If it's too high then the you assign the middle to the end and repeat. If it's too low you assign the middle to the start and repeat.

Comment: thank you i got it now